# браузер считает любой блок на странице полем для ввода текста

Tags: google-chrome

[image: img]

На любой странице появляется мигающая дрянь которая цепляется к блоку и считает что туда можно ввести текст, как пофиксить?

Comment: удалите сомнительные расширения / переустановите браузер

Answer (score 0):

Отключите настройку
Настройки=>Спец. возможности=>Навигация по страницам с помощью курсора.
Или нажмите просто нажмите F7